# Is there a way to control camera exposure (darker/lighter) in ActionScript/Flash control?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, camera

Is it possible to control camera exposure compensation from ActionScript?

Comment: What platform are you looking to do this on?

Comment: My bad. I should have been more explicit. Vanilla Adobe Flash control on an Internet web-page

Answer (score 1):

it is! Therefore you need to use a [ANE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) (Adobe Native Extension).

I found one for iOS here https://code.google.com/p/diadraw-air-camera-native-extension/ and maybe this https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-ImagePicker (supperts iOS and Android) serves for your purpose as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this sort of finer hardware control needs more access to the camera than flash plugin in a web page will have.

You'd be able to do it with a native extension in an AIR application but not with the flash plugin. Though I haven't seen any for desktop cameras, I imagine the hardware is even more variable than Android and would be a big endeavour. Definitely are a few around for Android/iOS (diadraw and I've done one myself for http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#camera).

But for the flash plugin I think you'll be limited to the controls in flash.media.Camera.